# Manhwa where the main lead gets reincarnated into a novel where the main character is her sister and she has 4 potential husbands

Tags: story-identification, manga

The female lead goes into a novel and her goal is to stop her sister from marrying an asshole and to instead marry someone else.

All the potential male leads bring their nephews and I know one of them is called Jacob and has golden hair.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Also, is one of the four potential husbands named "Jacob" or is one of the nephews?  And why are the nephews important at all that the "potential husbands" brought them?

Comment: Is there a less colourful description you can think of besides 'asshole'?

Answer (score 4):

This is *[The Little Lady Behind the Scenes](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-little-lady-behind-the-scenes)*. It is licensed by [Tapas](https://tapas.io/series/the-little-lady-behind-the-scenes/info).

> Julianne is as close to perfect as it gets: she’s got looks, talent, and smarts. The only problem is she has terrible taste in men! That’s why her little sister Lilianne is doing everything she can to make sure she doesn’t end up with the wrong guy. However, Julianne’s suitors are quickly catching on that the way to her heart is through Lilianne’s sweet tooth! How far will Lilianne go to set her sister up with the right man? Who will be the sweetest suitor?

It's not mentioned in the synopsis but this is a reincarnation story; the protagonist finds herself in a book world after falling asleep. As she is aware of the contents of the novel, she is aware that her sister's prospects are terrible, and decides to intervene.

[image]

None of the characters are named Jacob. The golden hair candidate is Cedric;

[image]

And it does include him bringing along his nephew, which leads to the other three bringing their own nephews, all the same age as the protagonist.